# Executing an if statement after a specific output in expect script

Tags: linux, expect

Is there a way to execute an if statement if I see a specific output? For example, when the console says "bad interpreter permission denied" I want to execute a command like "dos2unix file_name"?

So the logic will be like the following,

```
if (output is "bad interpreter permission denied")
{
  send dos2unix file_name
}
fi
```

This is an expect script.

Edit:

Could I do something like this in an expect script?

```
if (grep -cim1 '^M$' lruload.sh) -eq 1; then
send dos2unix filename
fi
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be bash or expect?

Comment: (Also, there are much better ways to detect if you need to run `dos2unix`; why not just test directly?)

Comment: Sorry guys, this is an expect script

Comment: Are you automating the process of sending a file to some server and then running it?

Comment: This still smells very much like a situation where following best practices would prevent the problem at hand from coming up in the first place; however, there's insufficient context given to address it more clearly. Anyhow -- if you want a native `expect` answer, you should probably also add the `tcl` flag, as expect scripts are natively written in TCL.

Comment: @glenn yes, that is exactly what I am doing. However, some of my files have script that are not unix formatted so I would have to convert the files first before running the script.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How can I prevent this from happening in the first place?

Comment: @kkmoslehpour, one improvement would be to run `dos2unix` unconditionally! It won't hurt anything if the file is already using UNIX newlines, and reduces the amount of conditional logic involved. For a better solution, I'd need to know more about the workflow that results in the file being on the system in the format it's in; there might be room for adjustment in SCM configuration, file transfer settings, or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

When you say execute the commands, I hope you meant to execute the command in the shell. You can use `exec` command for this purpose.

I'm not sure where you are interacting. I mean like telnet or ftp or bash. Anyway, under any case, you will be sending a command and expecting a prompt.

```
send "command 1"
expect "prompt"
send "command 2"
expect {
    timeout { puts "timeout happened"}

    "bad interpreter per mission denied" {
         set result [exec dos2unix <filename>]
     }
}
# if need to intact with three application, further use 'send' and 'expect'
```

You have the `result` variable to store the `dos2unix` output.

Answer (score 0):

How about this logic/psuedo-code?

```
export cmdText=`myCmd param1 param2 2>&1`
if ($cmdText is "bad interpreter permission denied")
{
    send dos2unix file_name
}
fi
```

The permission denied text probably went to stderr, not stdout, so the redirect 2>&1 lumps both of them together, making the test simple.